# How to generate geoJson data?

Tags: json, geojson

I want to generate geoJson data for an country and its all the states. In all the examples I have seen, all the data is for USA.

I would like to know where and how can  I get geoJson data for other countries and its corresponding all the states? Is it even possible?

Comment: I documented my steps for generating geoJSON for country regions here
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17267249/352311

Answer (score 4, accepted):

geojson data for individual countries and the world: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/

Comment: this is a very interesting resource... but are this files really in geojson format? I tried to convert them to topojson, but it didn't work. They seem to be rather csv than json...

Comment: its actually "The data format is tab-delimited text in utf8 encoding"...you need to convert it

Answer (score 5):

Includes all countries, in addition to the US and all US states.

https://github.com/johan/world.geo.json

Comment: Is it easy to remove countries, so that I end up with just 1 or 2 countries?

Comment: Countries in this data set are each contained in a different file, so it is very easy to get just the country or countries you need.