# Defining Regions in a US Map Using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I am displaying a very basic map of the US; just the states.  What I'm looking for is a good method for dividing the map into regions, with a single hover (all the states in the region change color) and click listener.

So far the best option if found is here: [How/Where do I get geoJSON data for states, provinces, and administrative regions of non-US countries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267248/how-where-do-i-get-geojson-data-for-states-provinces-and-administrative-region)

That seems like a lot more work than it should be.  Anyone have suggestions for a better method than importing 50 different shape files, and manually editing them into regions?

Comment: How is your map set up? If each state is an SVG, you can just give them each a class based on their region.

Comment: Have a look at this post from Mike Bostock: [Let's Make a Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/). He walks you through the whole process... getting the data, using the command line tools for topojson, loading it in d3, styling the regions, adding labels, etc.

Comment: I'm looking at the Let's Make a Map example, it doesn't do exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm not finding any good information on how to do that.  I need to merge multiple features (states) into a single feature (region).  So when I'm drawing the map in D3, it's drawing each region as a whole, not with the individual states.  Suppose this has become more of a geojson problem than D3 problem.

Answer (score 2):

This demo is near what you want:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4060606/
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json

What you're going to want to do is manipulate the us.json file; offhand I don't see state names but I see ids, create your regions by merging states in the region into one ID. 
try applying your own onclick/hover, if you can't get it, share what you tried and we'll go from there.